# Is it possible to use OpenCV or similar library in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, artificial-intelligence, face-detection

Can we use OpenCV from Javascript? Is there such implementation?

Is there any JS libraries that can be used for detecting face elements in the picture or video?

Comment: [jsfeat](https://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/) does a lot of similar stuff, is very lightweight, and is pure js.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there is any way of using openCV in JS other than communicating with a server with openCV on it and doing the processing there.

There is one Face detection algo in JS that I know of:  http://badassjs.com/post/1461943420/face-detection-in-javascript-via-html5-canvas

Comment: do you know any way to access camera from js?

Comment: @BohdanVoloshyn refer getUSerMedia (webrtc)

Comment: now opencv is also available in Javascript as opencv.js (Ported to JS using Emscripten into asm.js format), for more info visit-
 https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html

Answer (score 29):

OpenCV has never been ported to JavaScript in its entirety, but individual parts and algorithms have:

- For **face and face element** detection (and other parts / objects), you could use [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/) or [HAAR.js](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js) which are ports of the OpenCV Object Detection based on Haar Feature Cascades.
- The very first **face detection** algorithm on the web found in [ccv](https://github.com/liuliu/ccv) also deserves a mention. Its classifier seems to be [less reliable](http://liuliu.me/eyes/javascript-face-detection-explained/#disqus_thread) than the one provided by OpenCV though.
- The [headtrackr](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr) library used for **facetracking** might also be of interest since it implements the camshift algorithm also found in OpenCV.

Comment: +1 to headtrackr: well designed API providing events or face tracking (position, width, height, angle), head tracking (position in relation to camera) and status (getUserMedia available, streaming, face detection, redetection, etc.)

Answer (score 19):

I recommend [OpenCVjs](https://github.com/sakiyamaK/OpenCVjs). This is javascript OpenCV library.

Comment: Too bad its all in Japanese!?

Comment: Here is an English version by the University of California Irvine: https://github.com/ucisysarch/opencvjs

Comment: @Kevin Wu, nice ! This should be an answer :-) I didn't that the question is closed : /

Answer (score 15):

I do not know of a full implementation of OpenCV in Javascript, however a good number of the algorithms from it are implemented in [JSFeat](https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat#readme) which is a Computer Vision library in Javascript.

I believe that it might be possible to compile bits of OpenCV with emscripten, but as far as I know, nobody has done that.

Comment: useful lib, however I wanted to detect faces when I had to use OpenCV

Comment: you might prefer something like http://neave.github.io/face-detection/ then (although the haar detector in jsfeat can be used for face detection).

Comment: and there's even running example for that: http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/sample_haar_face.html

Answer (score 15):

Porting OpenCV to Javascript should be doable using asm.js which can compile C or C++ to Javascript

Another take: OpenCV is ported to Chrome Native Client: http://opencv.org/opencv-ported-to-google-chrome-nacl-and-pnacl.html

Comment: This should be the top answer. It's a disadvantage of StackOverflow, tech/information changes over time.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/uaRH2R62WOk

Answer (score 6):

Excellent repo for that here: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv
Doesn't seem to have full opencv functionality, but has face detection and great support for image streams coming from sources like an ar-drone.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be very good.
http://trackingjs.com/
Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your second question **[clmtrackr](https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr)** looks very promising. It ...

> ... is a javascript library for fitting facial models to faces in videos or images. It currently is an implementation of constrained local models fitted by regularized landmark mean-shift, as described in Jason M. Saragih's paper. clmtrackr tracks a face and outputs the coordinate positions of the face model as an array.

Try out [this example](http://auduno.github.io/clmtrackr/examples/modelviewer_pca.html) to have a look at their model.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those mentioned, there is another repo for "opencvjs"

https://github.com/blittle/opencvjs

It's a little unclear which of them (if any) are supposed to be canonical

Comment: none of them, they're all 3rd party